# Issue with Boost 1.64 and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I'm upgrading the libraries to MSVC 141 and moving to Visual Studio 2017.

I've downloaded the newest Boost libraries (boost_1_64_0_b2-msvc-14.1-64.exe). When building the code, I get this error:

> ...\boost\move\detail\type_traits.hpp(757): error C2187: syntax error:
>   ')' was unexpected here ...\boost\move\detail\type_traits.hpp(763):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'boost::move_detail::is_copy_constructible' being compiled

In the mentioned header, `BOOST_MOVE_TT_CXX11_IS_COPY_CONSTRUCTIBLE` is defined but the latest MSVC doesn't understand the enclosed code.

Undefining this macro helps, but it there a better solution to fix this? What's the reason here?

Comment: I got the same error, I'm new to C++ so I don't really know how to fix it.
In the meantime, I've added the following define before importing ptree.hpp

#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DECLTYPE

I'm sure there is a better way, I just don't know which one :)

Comment: Oh and I am using Boost v1.63

Comment: In my case, it turned out to be that `U` is defined as a macro (by cpprestsdk), conflicting with the Boost code. I just need to move the inclusion of Boost header files first.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/836), undefine macro `U` after each inclusion of cpprest headers or before inclusion of boost headers.

Example:

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#undef U
```

Comment: This or include the boost headers before including cpprest headers works too.

Comment: This is a little obscure, but if anyone uses the MetaTrader 4 Manager API this is also a problem with that library. #include "MT4ManagerAPI.h"
#undef U //clashes with boost

Comment: Due to the possibility of clashes with other Libraries (which sure may be coded poorly), it would be better if Boost used variable names that are unlikely to clash.

Comment: after calling #undef, this can to avoid "U: unknown idenftifier": help utility::conversions::to_string_t()

Answer (score 2):

need include -

*#define _TURN_OFF_PLATFORM_STRING*

"#include <*cpprest/details/basic_types.h*>"

....

see:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/836

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please consider using the space provided to include relevant info from your link. also please consider using the code format for your commands/code